# Index of substring in a python list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

How can I extract the index of a substring in a `python` list of strings (preferentially in a rapid way to handle long lists)?

For example, with `mylist = ['abc', 'day', 'ghi']` and character `'a'`, I would like to return `[0, 1, -1]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) with a list comprehension:

```
L = ['abc', 'day', 'ghi']

res = [i.find('a') for i in L]

# [0, 1, -1]
```

As described in the docs:

> Return the lowest index in the string where substring `sub` is found
>   within the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments `start` and `end` are
>   interpreted as in slice notation. Return `-1` if `sub` is not found.

Comment: Thanks jpp! That's exactly what I needed. I had failed to place the outer brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Or with index

```
l = ['abc','day','ghi']
[e.index('a') if 'a' in l else -1 for e in l]
```