# Return list of string if substring is in list of strings

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a sort of list lookup that does not need to be exact to return an output. I want to be able to enter as many letters as I want, then have the program return a word that would match.

```
words=["apple","banana","orange"]
```

If the user inputted "ng", it would return orange. But if the user typed "an", banana and orange would return. "a" would return all the items on this list.
I've been trying to google this for forever but I have clearly not been asking the right questions. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Index of substring in a python list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705809/index-of-substring-in-a-python-list-of-strings)

Comment: What does "Ctr + F" have to do with anything?

Comment: I just said "Ctr + F" because that was the easiest way to explain it i guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
words=["apple","banana","orange"]
query = "an" # string to search for
selected = [w for w in words if query in w]
```

In the above example, `selected` is:

```
['banana', 'orange']
```

Answer (score 0):

a = ['what', 'who', 'wholesome']
b = 'w' 
for i in a:
    if b in i:
        print(i)

Here b is your search string

Comment: Hey Abdullah, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain your answers by writing a few statements and code snippet, so that it would be easy to understand for others as well. Always use coding format when inserting code statements.